# update the _class property in all documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-mongo

I am using mongo with spring and I have the _class property in many documents in different collections, at some point I changed my package names and that caused errors with old documents that have the older package name in the _class property. what would be the best way to update the package name in the _class property in all the collections and documents ?

I managed to write a script that does the change for a specific collection ( it also requires recursion as some documents have some nested sub documents ). but I want a solution that would work for all collections.

I tried to just convert the document to a string replace the package name and convert back to json but that caused

```
_id: ObjectId("5500697dee854093136467ef")
```

to convert into

```
"_id" : {
        "str" : "5500697dee854093136467ef"
}
```

Any simple way to achieve this kind of update task ?

Comment: You need to perform the update operation on each collection. MongoDB never operates on more than one collection at once so each collection needs to receive a separate update operation.

Comment: yes, but I want one update script I can run on each collection, and not have to write different code for each collection.

Comment: You can write one command for each collection and just iterate through a list of collection names and send the update to each one.